# Dynamic loading icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi have a script that import location, which consists of multiple svg file and a index.ts file to import and export them.

```
import * as Icons from '../../icons'
```

I then have a functional component that returns the icon based on the icon name, which I am getting error.

```
interface props extends React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> {
  icon: string
  title?: string | undefined
}

function Icon({ icon, ...props }: props) {
  const Icon = Icons[icon] <= error here
  return <Icon {...props} />
}

function SidebarContent() {
  return (
  //some code here
  <Icon className="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" icon={route.icon} />
  //some code here
  )
}
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("d:/Code/JS/meal-order/frontend/src/icons/index")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("d:/Code/JS/meal-order/frontend/src/icons/index")'.ts(7053)
```

I would like to know how in the Icon component. How can it accept icon name (Icon[icon]) and return the correct icon? or probably there is other way to do this ?

More info:
If I write the code like the following then it works without complaining. However that doesn't fit the purpose because my intention is to dynamically load the icon based on the icon name i've passed.

```
function Icon({ icon, ...props }: props) {
  const Icon = Icons.ButtonsIcon
  return <Icon {...props} />
}
```

Update:
This is how I fix the type error:

```
import react from "react";
import * as Icons from "../../icons";

type IIcon = React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & {
  title?: string | undefined;
}>

export default function Icon({ icon = 'MenuIcon', ...props }) {
  const myObj: { [index: string]: IIcon } = Icons
  const NewIcon = myObj[icon]
  return <NewIcon {...props} />
}
```

Comment: Does changing the data type of `icon` in `props` from `icon: string` to `icon: keyof typeof Icons` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

Here's a CodeSandbox of what I believe you're trying to do.

## Icon.js

```js
import react from "react";
import * as Icons from "./icons";

export default function Icon({ icon, ...props }) {
  const NewIcon = Icons[icon];
  return <NewIcon {...props} />;
}
```

## Icons/index.js

```
import { ReactComponent as ButtonIcon } from "./button.svg";
import { ReactComponent as BellIcon } from "./bell.svg";

export { BellIcon, ButtonIcon };
```

## App.js

```
import Icon from "./Icon";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Icon icon="BellIcon"></Icon>
      <Icon icon="ButtonIcon"></Icon>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/frosty-stitch-li3wiz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

If you posted a codesandbox I could assist better that way, however, as long you Icons are components themselves, not just SVGs, it should work.

Comment: I've change the original code a bit. the variable I passed to the Icons[] should be 'icon' not a 'name'

Comment: by the way I still see the same error even I change the code as per your advise. The issue seems to be with Icon[icon].

Comment: I have updated the answer. Apologies for misunderstanding at first glance. Does this clear it up a bit ?

Comment: If I follow what you did in the sandbox link above. The error become:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("d:/Code/JS/meal-order/frontend/src/icons/index")'.ts(7053)

Comment: this is how my code is in codesandbox. However it is giving different error. Not sure if it helps.
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wood-911v9y?file=/src/icons/index.ts

Comment: are you using create react app? Here's the conflict with importing SVGs like that https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/

Comment: Yes I am using CRA. The article said that it is possible to import the SVG and use it directly as React Component. I shouldn't do that ??

Comment: Yeah I mean it's hard to say why it's not working without having your environment fully set up on my machine. Apologies, but if you can push it to github, I'd be happy to look at it

Comment: Here's the corrected version of importing SVGs directly in the file. https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bhaskara-8suiev?file=/src/App.js. The problem with the sandbox you sent me, was that you didn't properly pass the right names into the `Icon` component inside `App.js`. But otherwise, it probably should work. If not let me know!

Comment: The error stop after I've added option "noImplicitAny": false in the tsconfig.json file. 
I am not sure what is this option are for, or if there is any unwanted side effect when I turn it off.

Comment: No implicit any is for Typescript! It makes your app strict in the sense that it won't allow you to have a function/variable that is *implied* as `any`.  So, for example, in this case, I believe `Icons` is the implicit any problem here. Since `Icons` is simply imported and isn't typed, Typescript doesn't know what values you can use with it, and thus doesn't even know what that item is since you're indexing an unknown property on a variable. 

`Icons['exampleName']`... there is no type that says `Icons` has an `Icon` of `exampleName`.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explain-about-noimplicitany-in-typescript/
Hopefully this might help!

Comment: Yes you are right. I've turn on the NoImplicitAny again and try to assign a type to the Icons. Now it works. Please see the update of the original code on how I do it. Do let me know if there is a better way :)

Comment: Above is the way you can implement them correctly. Does that make sense?